Are all finitely generated kuratowski monoids finite?
Given a topological space $(X, \tau)$ we denote the $\mathscr{M}_{\tau}$ to be the smallest $\mathscr{M} \subseteq \mathscr{P}(X)^{\mathscr{P}(X)} $
such that:

$\mathscr{M}$ is a monoid for $\circ$
$c \in \mathscr{M}$ (where $c$ is the complement operator)
$\overline{\tau} \in \mathscr{M}$ (it contains the closure operator)
Given $ f_1 , f_2 $ in $\mathscr{M}$ ; $ f: S \mapsto f_1(S) \cap f_2(S)$ is in $ \mathscr{M}$ we'll denote it $ f_1 \land f_2$  (finite meets)

A submonoid of $ M \subseteq \mathscr{M}_{\tau}$ ($M$ satisfies (1) but not necessarily (2 - 4)) is called a kuratowski monoid.
Example: the kuratowski closure-complement monoid $\langle c,\overline{\tau}\rangle$ that has at most 14 elements.
Let $M$ a finitely generated kuratowski monoid of some space $(X,\tau)$. 
Is $M$ finite ?

I think the following gives a cheap example: Let $(X,\tau)$ be the discrete space of natural numbers. Let $\mathcal M$ be the monoid generated by "complement" and an operation "S" defined below,  via "composite" and "intersection". (I don't need "closure" because the topology is discrete.) Define $S:\mathcal P(\mathbb N)\to \mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ by letting $S(X)$ be $X\cup\{m\}$ where $m$ is the smallest natural number not in $X$, or $X$ itself if $X=\mathbb N$ (so there is no $m$). This $\mathcal M$ is finitely generated as a Kuratowski monoid (not as a plain monoid, since we need the "intersection" operation), but it is infinite because the iterates $S^{\circ n}$ of $S$ are all distinct (since $S^{\circ n}(\varnothing)=\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$, different for every $n$).

Sorry, I don't understand how $S$ is in $\mathscr{M}_{\tau}$. I also edited the question to make the defintion of "kuratoswski" monoid less ambiguous.

The $\mathcal M$ in my answer contains $S$ because it's defined as being generated by two elements, one of which is $S$.

This example may not be a "kuratowski monoid" as you didn't show that you can construct S using closure, complement, finite meets, and composition.
